# How to change my android project to specific version count (0.1, 0.2, 0.3...)?

Tags: android, version

Before I'm uploading my app to play store, is there any way to count the version of my app?
Version 0.1 and later 0.2 and so on.

Comment: Do you mean "how to specify version name of the app"? If yes, you should look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Comment: In your mainManifest file use the tag VERSION CODE and VERSION NUMBER. Version code can do the counting.